# AWS Amazon offers 160GB space for small instance. On booting Suse linux the total root partition space is

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, diskspace

AWS Amazon offers 160GB space for small instance. On booting Suse linux the total root partition space I got is 10GB. On df -h I only see/dev/sda1 with 10GB space. Where is rest 150GB? How can I claim this space? I dont want to use EBS as it cost extra and 160GB space suffice my need. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

The extra 150GB is given as an ephemeral storage, e.g. data on this storage won't survive reboots in contrast to the data on your root storage. During launching, you can select where your ephemeral disks should be made available as a device in your machine (this is the `-b`option when using the command line or in the "Instance Storage" tab when launching via the S3 console. You can then simply mount it in your running instance.

Comment: Yes, and be careful that you understand the storage options. On-instance storage is _ephemeral_. That means it vanishes when the instance is terminated. If you want data storage to be _persistent_, you need to mount an EBS volume or push your data into S3.

Comment: And the stories are numerous about people who had no clue what they were doing, and when there instance was stopped lost all their data. So please please please use EBS unless you really know what you're doing.